# correctness of functional iteration and contraction proof

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I need to prove: If $F$ is contractive from $[a, b]$ to $[a, b]$ and $x_{n+1} = F(x_n)$ with $x_0\in[a,b]$ then $|x_n -s| \leq C\lambda^n$ for an appropriate $C$ where $s$ is a fixed point of $F(x)$. I also would like to find an upper bound for $C$.

Here is what I have so far:

\begin{align}
|x_n-s| =& |F(x_{n-1})- F(s)| \\
        \leq&\lambda|x_{n-1}-s| \\
        =& \lambda|F(x_{n-2})-F(s)| \\
        \leq& \lambda^2|x_{n-2}-s| \\
        \vdots& \\
        \leq&\lambda^n|x_0 -s|
\end{align}
$\implies C=|x_0-s|$. Is this sufficient? I don't like having an $s$ on both sides of the equation. But I could say $(b-a) \geq C$ and thus:
\begin{equation}
|x_n-s| \leq (b-a)\lambda^n
\end{equation}

I could use this as my upper bound.

1. Is this correct?
2. What improvements would you suggest?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which definition of contractive do you use?

Comment: $|F(x) - F(y)| \leq \lambda|x-y|$ for $\lambda < 1$

Comment: Yes, it's correct. For $C$, I would recommend choosing either $\max \{s-a,\,b-s\}$ or $b-a$, to get independence of the starting point. And instead of working bckwards from $\lvert x_n - s\rvert$, I would prefer induction, $\lvert x_0 - s\rvert \leqslant C$ by definition of $C$, whichever $x_0$ is chosen. Then $\lvert x_{n+1}-s\rvert \leqslant \lambda\cdot\lvert x_n - s\rvert \leqslant \lambda\cdot C\cdot\lambda^n$.

Comment: I like your suggestion! I'll keep that in mind for proofs in the future.